# how to loop through all the entries in excel sheet in selenium python

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

So I am using selenium for my web automation. I have a excel sheet with my data entries. Right now I am able to fill my excel entries but its filling only first entry after that my program just stops. I have more than 1,50,000 entries. I want my program to keep running until it fills all the entries in my form. How do I do that. Please help me !

**My Entries in excel**

[image]

**My code**

```
from sre_parse import State
from tkinter.tix import Select
from unicodedata import name
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")




# readign the excel file
df  = pd.read_excel('Rajnandgaon_List2.xlsx')

# looping through all the data

for i in df.index:

    time.sleep(3)
    # selcting states
    state_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="State"]')
    drp1 = Select(state_select)

    drp1.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')

    time.sleep(2)


    # selecting district
    district_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="District"]')
    drp2 = Select(district_select)

    drp2.select_by_visible_text('RAJNANDGAON')
    entry = df.loc[i]

    # entering the age
    age = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/input')

    age.send_keys(str(entry['age']))

    # respondant name
    rs_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input')
    rs_name.send_keys(entry['name'])

    # rs mobile number
    rs_number = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/input')
    rs_number.send_keys(str(entry['mobile number']))

    # rs gender
    gender = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/select')
    rs_gender = Select(gender)
    rs_gender.select_by_visible_text('Male')



    # submitting the form
    submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[5]/input')
    submit.click()


    # second page
    # radio button 1
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]/input')
    radio_1.click()



    # radio button 2
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()


    # radio button 3
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()

    # radio button 4
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()


    # radio button 5
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()


    submit2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input')
    submit2.click()
```

Comment: What happens after the last click is it still on the same page?

Comment: yes. Its just stops there in the last page. I want it to close the browser and then start a new one for each entry until it finishes filling all the entry.

Comment: Why not just go back to the starting url with driver.get().

Comment: How ? Can you show my by example code please

Comment: after for i in df.index: driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solve using below code:

```
from sre_parse import State
from tkinter.tix import Select
from unicodedata import name
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import time
import openpyxl


# readign the excel file
ExcelPath = 'Excel_Path'
df = pd.read_excel(ExcelPath)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(ExcelPath)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
maxrow = ws.max_row

# looping through all the data
for i in range(2, maxrow + 1):
    # Every Time Browser will open
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")
    time.sleep(3)
    # selcting states
    state_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="State"]')
    drp1 = Select(state_select)

    drp1.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')

    time.sleep(2)

    # selecting district
    district_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="District"]')
    drp2 = Select(district_select)

    drp2.select_by_visible_text('RAJNANDGAON')
    entry = df.loc[i]

    # entering the age
    age = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/input')

    age.send_keys(str(entry['age']))

    # respondant name
    rs_name = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input')
    rs_name.send_keys(entry['name'])

    # rs mobile number
    rs_number = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/input')
    rs_number.send_keys(str(entry['mobile number']))

    # rs gender
    gender = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/select')
    rs_gender = Select(gender)
    rs_gender.select_by_visible_text('Male')

    # submitting the form
    submit = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[5]/input')
    submit.click()

    # second page
    # radio button 1
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]/input')
    radio_1.click()

    # radio button 2
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()

    # radio button 3
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()

    # radio button 4
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()

    # radio button 5
    radio_1 = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]')
    radio_1.click()

    submit2 = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="zed_user_form"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input')
    submit2.click()
    # After Clicking Submit Button Browser Will Quit
    driver.quit()
```